# User controls in Visual Studio 2013 Express?

Tags: c#, winforms

I cant find Windows Forms Control Library in my projecttemplates or in the "online"-option? Is it renamed or simply not included in Express version?

Edit: 
Maybe Class library is what Im searching for? I want to create a user control for winforms, but that class library dont recognize winforms components and I cant use

```
using System.Windows.Forms
```

Can I do a work around in class library? Or do I need the full version of VS?

Comment: Which version of VS 2013 express is installed? "Express 2013 for Web" or "Express 2013 for Windows" or "Express 2013 for Windows Desktop"?

Comment: Sorry, Im using Express 2013 for Windows Desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Class Library** actually is what you need but it is better in your case to chose **Winforms Program** because that way all references are set up.

When you have created it change it's project type to **class library** in the properties tab.

Note: The `using` clauses just make it simpler to reference the classes in the assemblies they refer to. But to get access to these they first must be added to your project's references. Look at the project expolorer - references.

The **Windows Forms Template** has all necessary assemblies already there while the **Class Library Template** doesn't and only has the bare minimum you need to write non-visual classes.

You can always add more references as needed with a right-click on the project explorer. Then you can navigate to the assemblies you need, like in your case `System.Windows.Forms`

And no, you don't need the full version for most things.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time. However, my problem is that I can't choose Winforms Program from the start :(

Comment: Why? I see it in the picture you posted. OK, to be exact they call it Windows Forms Application now, but that's what you should go for.

Comment: Ahh, you are right. I mixed it up, I was really looking for Windows Forms Control Library. I'm guessing they removed that library for Class Library. I did really appreciate your answer, it was really helpful. And it is a good tip, thank you sir! In the long run, I dont like solutions where you cannot see what have been done (i.e creating a winforms app and later remade it to a class library) but this will, for sure,  come in handy. However, for this particular case I think I rather use a Class Library and manage with assemblies. Accepted!

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee712572%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), you should be a able to find this option in Extensibility -> Installed templates.

> In the New Project dialog box, under Installed Templates, expand the
>   node for your preferred programming language and then select
>   Extensibility. In the list of project types, select Windows Forms
>   Toolbox Control.

Comment: I was looking for something like this. However, I dont think we're looking on the same dialog :( This is what I see when I try to create a new project in Express version for Desktop 2013. http://postimg.org/image/704j35u5n/